# Update code for meteor production app (self hosting)

Tags: meteor

I have production app running on Digital Ocean. I need to revise the code. It easy with meteor.com hosting:

```
meteor deploy xxx
```

How do I update production app with self hosting like Digital Ocean?

Thank You

Comment: How did you deploy your app to Digital Ocean before? Did you use mup?

Comment: @Areca Yes, `mupx` to be precise

Comment: You need to do mup deploy again. It will update automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should re-deploy with mupx to update your app on prod.

Comment: Is that will remove database?

Comment: No, there is an option "setupMongo" in mupx.json. If it is true, it will install if the server does not have a mongodb instance installed. You can set it to false, if you want to be sure.

Comment: That's my concern. Thank you.